# results from if statement

Tags: python, if-statement, eoferror

*EDIT: solved another way
grades=[71,70,72]
results=['y','n','x']
for index, grade in enumerate(grades):
    grades.index(grade)
    if grade in grades:
        grade=input('grade:  ')
        print (grades[index], results[index])*
.....................................................................................

My code was supposed to give

```
>>>71
[71, 'y']
>>>70
[70, 'n']
>>>72
[72, 'error']
```

but it takes random(?) values form my if statement. It gives

```
>>> 
grade: 71
[72, 'n']
grade:
```

Also, I'm getting an EOFerror at the input() line and the same if I put raw_input()

The code is:

```
grades = [70,71,72]
result1 = 'y'
result2 = 'n'
result3 = 'error'
r = 'x'
grade = input('grade: ')

def get_result(r):   
    """
    (str) -> (str)
    you're in or out

    >>>71
    [71, 'y']

    >>>70
    [70, 'n']

    >>>72
    [72, 'error']

    """

    r = 'x'
    for grade in grades:
        list=[grade, r]

        if grade is 71:
            r = result1             
        elif grade is 70:
            r = result2           
        else:
            r = result3           
    return(list)
print(get_result(r))
```

Comment: @Neal Python, obviously.

Comment: Try using ``if grade == 71:``...  ``is`` means something slightly different than ``==``

Comment: when I use if grade == 71: it gives [72, 'y'] instead of [72,'n'] but I still need [71,'y']

Comment: Hum, couple comments. First, dont **ever** use list as a var name. You will overwrite a python keyword and bad thing will happen. Second, your r param is overwritted as soon as you enter the function. Why do you even put it here?

Comment: @jwpat7: the result of `==` and `is` is *not* the same for integers in general.  Try `x = 10000`; `y = 10000`, `print x is y` entered on three separate lines in the console.

Comment: @DSM, I deleted my comment, although it holds for integers up to 256

Comment: @jwpat7: which integer objects are preconstructed varies across the Python implementations (I'm assuming you only tested CPython) -- it behaves differently in IronPython, Jython, and PyPy.  It's an interpreter-implementation detail and can't be relied on.

Answer (score 4):

```
r = 'x'
for grade in grades:
    list=[grade, r]

    if grade is 71:
        r = result1             
    elif grade is 70:
        r = result2           
    else:
        r = result3
return(list)
```

None of these `if` statements is going to change anything, because you've already created `list=[grade, r]` with the old value of `r`, and never do anything with the new value of `r`.

Try moving the `list=[grade, r]` after the `if` statements.

However, while you're at it, you really shouldn't name a variable `list`, because that's the name of a built-in type.

And also, you don't do anything with the variable but return it, so you don't even really need it anyway.

So:

```
    if grade is 71:
        r = result1             
    elif grade is 70:
        r = result2           
    else:
        r = result3
    return [grade, d]
```

However, you've got a few other problems with your code. For one thing, you're looping over the `grades`, each of which redefines `list`, so you're only returning the last one. So what's the point of the loop? I think you want something like this:

```
retval = []
for grade in grades:
    r = 'x'
    if grade is 71:
        r = result1             
    elif grade is 70:
        r = result2           
    else:
        r = result3
    retval.append([grade, r])
return retval
```

Also, you might want to consider putting the results into a `dict`, instead of into three separate variables, because it will make your code a lot simpler:

```
results = { 71: 'y', 70: 'n', 72: 'error' }
retval = []
for grade in grades:
    retval.append([grade, results.get(grade, 'x')])
return retval
```

And you might recognize that pattern of "make an empty list, do a trivial loop around appending to it" as exactly what a list comprehension is for, so you can make this even simpler:

```
results = { 71: 'y', 70: 'n', 72: 'error' }
return [[grade, results.get(grade, 'x')] for grade in grades]
```

Meanwhile, why are you passing an `r` parameter to `get_result`, when you never access it, and in fact you rebind `r` to a local variable? (If you run `pylint` or a similar tool, it will catch problems like this.) Maybe what you really want is a `grades` parameter?

From your later comment, it sounds like what you actually want is a `grade` parameter, so you can get the result for a specific grade. You don't need to loop over every grade for that. Let's rewrite things a bit:

```
def get_result(grade):
    return [grade, results.get(grade, 'x')]
```

That's it. Now, here's the whole script:

```
results = { 71: 'y', 70: 'n', 72: 'error' }

def get_result(grade):
    return [grade, results.get(grade, 'x')]

grade = input('grade: ')
print(get_result(grade))
```

Comment: I'm trying option 1 (retval) and it rejects 'return retval.

Comment: Well, list comprehension are cool and all, but if the OP is at the same level of knowledge than the students I tutored in an introduction to programming course, it may be better to stick to `if` and `while` and simple variable assignments. Those basic things are actually pretty hard to grasp initially.

Comment: The retval option gives me the correct combinations but for every grade. I mean I enter e.g. 70 and gives grade: 70
[[70, 'n'], [71, 'y'], [72, 'error']]

Comment: @wanderer: You're not passing the input `grade` into the function, so there's no way the function can know which combination you want. I assumed, since you were looping over all of the grades and trying to make a list, you wanted to return that list. Now that I understand what you're trying to do (I think), see the edited answer.

Comment: @LaurentBourgault-Roy: That's why I wrote it the explicit way first. The OP can look at the explicit loop and the comprehension side by side (or the vertical equivalent thereof). If that's not enough to understand the comprehension, he's still got the explicit loop.

Comment: @abarnert Thanks for the detailed answer, now I see my code was trying to achieve something different than what I had in mind and it was all wrong, too. I am working on the get_result(grade) edit, testing a few things to get rid of 'x' and print y,n,error.

Comment: @LaurentBourgault-Roy The OP's level might be worse than your students! Complicated solutions are good because we're learning in the process, though.

Comment: @wanderer: The reason I had the `'x'` there was because your code set `r='x'` before the loop, so I assumed that's what you wanted for an invalid value (like calling `get_result(60)`). What _do_ you want to do in that case? Is it OK if the program raises an exception and terminates?

Comment: @abarnert It was supposed to give e.g for typing 71   >>>71
[71, 'y'] 
the r='x' was an attempt, it's not compulsory. If grade isn't in grades, it should give an error, if it's in grades it should display results for each grade we input.

Comment: @wanderer: OK, got it. It sounds like you have a handle on things, and if you get stuck, you'll be able to ask a new question for followup, right?

Comment: @abarnert yes, I'll give it a few tries and see if I can get it. Thanks.